# The cheapest path in the graph

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I am supposed to decide, if the statement is true or false and use arguments for my answer.

In every weighted n-vertices graphs:

1. with no negative weighted edges,
2. with n>10,
3. in which every weighted edge appears constant number of times(e.g. 1,2,3.., but not n number of times), but graphs, in which every edge has the same value, does not satisfy this condition,

there exists between every two vertices at most 4*n^3.

I tried to draw some graphs and I conclude that all of them satisfy my conditions. But I do not have general explanation.

So is that true? If not, can you say me some counter example?

Thanks.

Comment: How does this relate to https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109494/755?  Can you credit the source where you originally encountered this problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109488/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56188408/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider cases where every weight is very large.

Comment: It came to low quality posts queue and it looks like a comment. What do you think?

Comment: @Evil I didn't want to post a complete answer because this looks like a homework question. If people don't like it, I'll delete it (or they can delete it for me, via the low quality queue).