# Is the number of shortest paths between every two vertices at most 4*n^3?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

In every weighted graph with $n$-vertices

- with negative weights,
- with $n > 10$,
- a weight can't appear $n$-times in graph,

there are between every two vertices at most $4n^3$ shortest paths.

I'm trying to prove whether the statement above is true or false, however I am clueless. So far I failed to find a graph where there would be more than $4n^3$ shortest paths so I'm guessing it's true?

Comment: How does this question relate to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109488/the-cheapest-path-in-the-graph/

Comment: @Zuran, do you mean "with **non**-negative weights"? "with negative weights" sounds rather strange, although whether the weights are negative or not does not affect the answer.

Comment: Can you credit the source where you originally encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following graph, where we have $3\times 4+1=13$ nodes, $a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4, a5$ and $4\times4=16$ edges $a1b1, a1c1, b1a2, c1a2, \cdots, a4b4, a4c4, b4a5, c4a5$ with weights $1,1,1,1,\cdots, 4,4,4,4$ respectively.

[image: Graph made by Apass.Jack using https://graphonline.ru/en/]
Every path from $a1$ to $a5$ is a shortest path between them since all of them have the same weight (length). There are $2^4=16$ of them.

Consider extending this graph to a much larger graph, following the same pattern. For example, suppose we will have $100\times3+1=301$ nodes and $100\times4+1=400$ edges. Now compute how many shortest paths there are between $a1$ and $a301$.

---

**Exercise 1.** Construct a graph with the same constraint such that there are more than $4n^3$ paths of the same weight between every two vertices.